# How to find duplicated combination were order does not matter in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2013, excel-2016

How to find duplicated combination in excel were order does not matter. I have tried using concatenation and sorting them out but its a waste of space, if only there was another way to achieve this without concatenating. Id truly appreciate it.

Example:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? "Waste of space" is relative. Why not use concatenation if it works? Will the data be numbers, or will it be text? That is an important factor!

Comment: Are they exactly four columns or could there be more? Also, is there any limit on the range of the numbers (e.g. maximum of 2 digits?)

Comment: I guess also would a VBA solution be of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exact 4 columns and up to 1000 rows:

```
{=IF(SUM(IF(MMULT({1,1,1,1},TRANSPOSE(COUNTIF($A1:$D1,$A$1:$D$1000)))=4,1))>1,"duplicate","unique")}
```

This is an array formula. Input it into `E1` without the curly brackets. Then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm.

Copy downwards as needed.

If it not works, please check the language version of your Excel and the locale of your Windows. Maybe the array constant `{1,1,1,1}` in my formula must be written as `{1\1\1\1}` or `{1.1.1.1}` because the comma will be in conflict with the decimal separator or list delimiter.

Comment: Sir can you achieve this with 6 combination using UDF vba?

Comment: This formula can easily be adapted for 6 columns using `{1,1,1,1,1,1}` and `A:F`. For `VBA` please ask a separate question. In that question please mention whether it can be possible or not that there are repeated values within one row.

Comment: Your question is downvoted and put on hold because 1. it is too broad - no code but two requirements - and 2. it shows that you are totally unfamiliar with Excel VBA. A `UDF` cannot place content anywhere into the sheet. It only can return *one* value for the cell, from which it is called as formula from. If I would be you, I would delete that question, engage me with `VBA` a little, try coding myself and then ask *one* concrete question where I am stuck with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter what version of excel you are using. Just click on the **Data** tab at the top.
Select the column where you seem to find the duplicates.
You can see **Remove Duplicates** listed somewhere, and you are done.

Else if you don't want to remove the values, try using the **Filter**. This will let you know what values are actually Duplicates.

Comment: It matters a lot sir! i am dealing with dynamic data where it changes constantly! i need a formula to monitor the generated combinations..

Comment: @MohdAslam - Have you tried your own suggestion on that data set? Excel does not find any duplicates in this scenario. I don't think you have understood the question.

Comment: i have tried it but i have to concatenated it and sorting it largest to smallest then counting it using countif formula.. now the thing is it extends my column. i wanted it to find duplicates using formula only without having to concatenate the values. thanks for debating with me..